# Oracle JSON aggregation

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

Like MongoDB JSON document aggregation, I'm not sure if aggregation of oracle JSON document is possible.

Below is the illustration / query

```
select key_col,'{"a":3,"b":8}' as ans
from
(
  select 1 as key_col,'{"a":1,"b":3}' json_col from dual
  union
  select 1 as key_col,'{"a":2,"b":5}' json_col from dual
)
group by key_col;
```

[image]

So, the ans column sums up value of a and b from inner query and again creates a single document corresponding to the key column.

I can definitely retrieve keys from json document using json_table and then sum those column and again json_object() those keys to form document, but would like to know if direct method of document aggregation through data pipelining is possible or not.

Any help or idea would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
with data as (
    select 1 as key_col,cast('{"a":1,"b":3}' as varchar2(4000)) json_col from dual
    union
    select 1 as key_col,'{"a":2,"b":5}' json_col from dual
)
select key_col, json_object(
    key 'a' is sum(a), 
    key 'b' is sum(b)
) as aggr
from (
    select * from data,
        json_table(
            json_col,
            '$'
            columns(
                a NUMBER path '$.a',
                b NUMBER path '$.b'
            )
        )
)
group by key_col
;
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this as said in question.. is there no in-built function in oracle which aggregates all keys in document without specifying key names?

Comment: No, but you could write your own as a PTF or backed by a OBJECT implementing ODCI interface.
CREATE FUNCTION json_sumagg(tab TABLE, 
                      json COLUMNS, keys COLUMNS, aggregated COLUMNS)
                  RETURN TABLE  
PIPELINED ROW POLYMORPHIC USING json_sumaggregate_pkg;
or
CREATE FUNCTION json_sumagg(tablename IN VARCHAR2, 
                      jsoncolname IN VARCHAR2, keynames SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST, aggregatednames SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST)
RETURN ANYDATASET PIPELINED USING json_sumaggregate_impl ;
depending on ORACLE version or your preference.